# Wiring Kitchen Lights: 6 lights a 3 way switch with 1 light within the 6 being controlled by another switch

Tags: wiring, lighting

I am remodeling my kitchen and changing the light configuration. Currently I have one large light for the full kitchen controlled by two switches and another light over the sink controlled by a different switch on a completely different circuit I believe.

I would like to change this so that I have 6 LED recessed lights that light the full kitchen via the two switches and have 1 light of the 6 controlled by the switch over the sink. My question: can this be done in general and if so what would the wiring diagram look like? Thanks.

Comment: Would the 1 light over the sink also be shut off with the other 5 using the 2 switches, or will control be totally independent?

Comment: Good question. I would like the light to be controlled with the other 5. But when the switch over the sink is switched on only the light over the sink is switched on.

Comment: Other than perhaps smart switches, you'll need to use a relay to isolate the switch to the old light. As to how to do this legally, I'll leave that to the pros. Where in the world are you?

Comment: I am in the US. All lights will be replaced with recessed LEDs. I should add that currently the light over the sink has a switch and power separate of the main switches. I know this is an odd thing to do but would make things a lot cleaner. I know I could add a 7th LED light and keep the wiring the same just trying to see if there is a way to keep from doing that.

Comment: Is there a reason you're bent on recessed cans for kitchen lighting? (They tend to throw light rather...down, which can be problematic, especially if you light the aisles with them instead of placing them over the counters, or if you have shiny, glare-prone countertops)

Comment: Mostly because its a small kitchen and this will add some perceived upward space to it. Its a galley kitchen so there will be two rows of three lights placed directly over the countertops so how they throw the light shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: After doing a little additional research into smart switches I think this might be the ticket. However I need a smart switch without a neutral (1950s home) and can be linked to other switches. Does anyone have an opinion on this or know of a switch that would work?

Comment: Have you looked inside the switch box and verified that no neutral is present, or are you presuming that neutral's not there?